# Predual of von Neumann algebra M is closed in the dual $M*$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-information

[image: Stephane Attal : Operator Algebras and Modular Theory]

I am reading Stephane Attals Book Open Quantum Systems 1, chapter Elements of Operator Algebras and Modular Theory. And have issues understanding the proof given here.

- **First** of all in the "introduction" why is $\Psi(M_1)$ compact in $\mathbb{C}$?
- **Second**: Is there an easy way to see why the $\sigma$-weak and weak topology coincide ?
- **Third**: in the proof (i) we should show $f\in M_*$ by showing that $f$ is actually weakly continuous. Since he already argued (my first point) that $M_* \subseteq M^*$ and the defined sequence $f_n \in M_*$ converges in $M^*$, $f\in M^*$ as well and because the topological dual of a space is the set of the continuous linear functionals, $f$ is continuous on $M$. Since $M_1 \subset M$, $f$ is contiuous on  $M_1$. Continuity is stronger than weak continuity. So why does weak continuity has to be shown and why not (if anything at all) continuity, which is required by the definition of $M_*$

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets.
2. Yes. A net $\{A_j\}$ converges weakly to $0$ if $A_jx\to0$ weakly for all $x\in H$. Meanwhile, $\sigma$-weak convergence is the fact that $\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}\tr(A_jR)\to0$ for all trace-class $R$. When $R$ is rank-one, say $Rx=\langle x,y\rangle z$, then
   $$
   \tr(A_jR)=\langle A_jx,y\rangle\,\|z\|\to0. 
   $$
   When $R$ is finite-rank, it is sum of rank-one operators, and the above gives $\tr(A_jR)\to0$ by linearity. In general, $R=\lim_nR_n$ with $R_n$ finite rank. Then, if $\|A_j\|\leq c$ for all $j$,
   $$
   |\tr(A_jR)|\leq|\tr(A_jR_n)|+|\tr(A_j(R-R_n)|\leq|\tr(A_jR_n)|+c\,\|R-R_n\|_1.
   $$
   This gives
   $$
   \limsup_j|\tr(A_jR)|\leq c\|R-R_n\|_1. 
   $$
   We are still free to choose $n$, so $\limsup_j|\tr(A_jR)|=0$, which shows that the limit exists and is zero.
3. *Continuity is stronger than weak continuity*. No. It's harder to be continuous in the weaker topology, not easier. You already know that $M_*\subsetneq M^*$, which in particular says that there are norm-continuous functionals which are not normal.